# Adding new action to an existing controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am new user for Rails so I am having a controller and then I added anew action for it then I added new view but when listing the routes I can't find the new action ; So how to add my new action to the active routes

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes

```
resources :ControllerName do
collection do
  get :NewActionName
  post :NewActionName
end
```

end

Make changes like this and it should work